# How to calculate normal distribution when its standard deviation is a function of another quantity?

Tags: python, statistics, normal-distribution

Recently, I was reading a paper. In which particle velocity mean, mu = 0 and standard deviation, sigma = b/D^2, where D is the diameter of the particle and b = 11000 um^2 is the fitting parameter. The inverse dependence allows the smaller particles to have higher initial velocity. It is also given that the mean diameter for the particles and standard deviation are 132 um and 45 um, respectively. So, based on this information I tried the following

```py
import numpy as np

da = 132*1e-06 # mean diameter
sd = 45*1e-06 # standard deviation in particle size
b = 11000*1e-12 # 11000 um^2

d = np.random.normal(da, sd, 100) # 100 randomly choosen particles

def norm(mu, sigma, x):
    return 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)) 

v = np.array([norm(0, b/(i**2), i) for i in d])
```

But the resulting velocity distribution came opposite for me. With larger particles having higher velocity.

[image: Particle size vs velocity]

Comment: isn't it `np.random.normal` ? Also, your output isn't reproducible. Please recheck. Moreover, there's typo in the posted code snippet.

Comment: yes sry for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear about what you expect from this function call.  This is a closed-form computation of a deterministic value, not a random event from a normal distribution.

```
def norm(mu, sigma, x):
    return 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))

norm(0, b/(i**2), i)
```

I think that the critical point is the expression `(x - mu)**2`; you seem to have used the diameter of each particle as its Z-score.  Instead, you need to pull a random value for each particle, and use *that* as the Z-score.  The built-in `normal` function does that for you.  For instance.

```
v = np.array([np.random.normal(0, b/(i**2), 1) for i in d])
```

Comment: ```v = np.array([np.random.normal(0, b/(i**2), 1) for i in d0])[:,0]```

```v = np.random.normal(0, /(d**2), 100)```

What is the difference between these two? Both produces significantly different distribution.

Comment: This is the paper I'm referring to https://doi.org/10.5194/acp-20-3181-2020

Comment: Actually I want randomly assign velocity to the particles but I didn't quite understand 1/d^2 dependence of SD and how to implement that.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you have to generate an individual value for each particle, based on that particle's diameter.  First you generate 100 random diamaters.  THen, for each diameter, you generate a random velocity based on that *particular* diameter.